# How to create inner table with PDFBox 2 and Boxable?

Tags: java, pdfbox, boxable

I am working with PDFBox v2 and boxable and I need to generate a cell with 2 rows inside.

I tried to make like [wiki](https://github.com/dhorions/boxable/wiki#making-inner-table) explains, but in my app cell content prints literally.
[image: table]

The code for generate inner table is:

```java
activeRow.createCell(100f, "<table><tr><td> R1 </td></tr><tr><td> R2 </td></tr></table>");
```

What is going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I respond to my own question.

The problem is call to `createCell()`. The correct method to create inner table is `createTableCell()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
     float margin = 80;
    // starting y position is whole page height subtracted by top and bottom margin
    float yStartNewPage = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - (2 * margin);
    // we want table across whole page width (subtracted by left and right margin ofcourse)
    float tableWidth = page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - (2 * margin);

    boolean drawContent = true;
    float yStart = yStartNewPage;
    float bottomMargin = 70;
    float yPosition = 550;
   cell = row.createTableCell((100), "", document, page, yPosition , bottomMargin, margin);
```

Create simple table cell inside table

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).